# Trying to insert variables into a string, keep getting undefined with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that accepts a license code and then returns a link element with the proper license code and description. I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong in the code, but I'm guessing in the if statements.

This is what I've got:

```js
function generateLicenseLink(licenseCode) {
  let code = licenseCode.replace("CC-", "").toLowerCase();
  let codeToTest = code.split(/-{3}/);
  let test = codeToTest;
  let codeShort;
  let codeLong;

  let link = `<a href ="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/${codeShort}/4.0/>${codeLong}</a>`;

  if (test === "by") {
    codeShort = "by";
    codeLong = "Creative Commons Attribution License";
  } else if (test === "by-nc") {
    codeShort = "by-nc";
    codeLong = "Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial License";
  } else if (test === "by-sa") {
    codeShort = "by-sa";
    codeLong = "Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License";
  } else if (test === "by-nd") {
    codeShort = "by-nd";
    codeLong = "Creative Commons Attribution-NoDerivs License";
  } else if (test === "by-nd-sa") {
    codeShort = "by-nd-sa";
    codeLong = "Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike License";
  } else if (test === "by-nc-nd") {
    codeShort = "by-nc-nd";
    codeLong = "Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs License";
  }

  return link;
}

console.log(generateLicenseLink("CC-BY"));
console.log(generateLicenseLink("CC-BY-NC"));
console.log(generateLicenseLink("CC-BY-SA"));
console.log(generateLicenseLink("CC-BY-ND"));
console.log(generateLicenseLink("CC-BY-NC-SA"));
console.log(generateLicenseLink("CC-BY-NC-ND"));
```

What I want to return would look something like: '[Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial License](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/)'

Thank you!

I've tried using switch instead of if statement, I've tried to format the URL differently, and tried to replace the "CC-" and split the elements at different points. It's all just coming up as undefined in the variables section, as such:

<a href ="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/undefined/4.0/>undefined

Comment: move `link` to after `if..else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong order of operations and missing destructuring `let [test] = codeToTest;`

```js
function generateLicenseLink(licenseCode) {
  let code = licenseCode.replace("CC-", "").toLowerCase();
  let codeToTest = code.split(/-{3}/);
  let [test] = codeToTest;
  let codeShort;
  let codeLong;

  if (test === "by") {
    codeShort = "by";
    codeLong = "Creative Commons Attribution License";
  } else if (test === "by-nc") {
    codeShort = "by-nc";
    codeLong = "Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial License";
  } else if (test === "by-sa") {
    codeShort = "by-sa";
    codeLong = "Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License";
  } else if (test === "by-nd") {
    codeShort = "by-nd";
    codeLong = "Creative Commons Attribution-NoDerivs License";
  } else if (test === "by-nd-sa") {
    codeShort = "by-nd-sa";
    codeLong = "Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike License";
  } else if (test === "by-nc-nd") {
    codeShort = "by-nc-nd";
    codeLong = "Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs License";
  }

  let link = `<a href ="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/${codeShort}/4.0/>${codeLong}</a>`;

  return link;
}

console.log(generateLicenseLink("CC-BY"));
console.log(generateLicenseLink("CC-BY-NC"));
console.log(generateLicenseLink("CC-BY-SA"));
console.log(generateLicenseLink("CC-BY-ND"));
console.log(generateLicenseLink("CC-BY-NC-SA"));
console.log(generateLicenseLink("CC-BY-NC-ND"));
```

Comment: I just tried this out, and it's still coming back as undefined.

Comment: @jonooo fixed, you had one more mistake

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the problem great. Just wondering though, what exactly does the square brackets around test do to the code overall? I don't think I've covered this yet in school. I'm a student currently, and not very far into JavaScript.

Comment: Same as `let test = codeToTest[0];`

Answer (score 0):

When you create an interpolated string, the values in the `${}` are evaluated immediately, they aren't "remembered" for when you later use the string. At the time you defined `link`, `codeShort` and `codeLong` were undefined.

Instead of defining `link` at the beginning of the function, first perform the logic to calculate `codeShort` and `codeLong`, and then only then define `link`.